# get request for local ip URL using file_get_contents() is not working

Tags: php

If I call an URL directly on browser, i will get response, but when I try to get contents from this URL using `file_get_contents` or `CURL` it returns nothing, get empty page (here am using url start with local ip address .eg :`http://192.168.x.xxx/device/reader-config?action=get`).

Is there any connection with local ip?

here is my code,

```
$url = 'http://192.168.x.xxx/device/reader-config?action=get';

$username = 'username';
$password = 'password';
$context = stream_context_create(array('http' => 
        array('header' => "Authorization: Basic " . base64_encode("$username:$password"))
    ));

$rawdata = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
print_r($rawdata);
```

Comment: Can you show the code that is causing the problem.

Comment: here is my code,

$url = 'http://192.168.x.xxx/device/reader-config?action=get';
 
 $username = 'username';
 $password = 'password';
$context = stream_context_create(array('http' => array('header' => "Authorization: Basic " . base64_encode("$username:$password"))));


$rawdata = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
print_r($rawdata);

Comment: Please add the code to the question as comments may be lost in the future.